# Put request working in curl, but not in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, http, python-requests

I am trying to make a 'put' method with curl everything is working fine and I got the JSON back:

```
curl -X PUT -d '[{"foo":"more_foo"}]' http://ip:6001/whatever?api_key=whatever
```

But for some reason when using the python `requests` module as follow:

```
import requests
url = 'http://ip:6001/whatever?api_key=whatever'

a = requests.put(url, data={"foo":"more_foo"})

print(a.text)
print(a.status_code)
```

I get the following error:

> 500 Internal Server Error
>
> ## Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

**NB:** The server is up and running.

Comment: The data structures are different between your examples. Also note you can pass URL query parameters differently in `requests`, rather than in the URL string: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls.

Comment: yeah, i know about the data structure, but requests fails if i put them like the exact one in curl. thanks for the query parameters, but i assume even if i pass them, it's still gonna behave like this.

Comment: What do you mean by *"fails"*? The current one also fails, so I assume it's different somehow? Give a [mcve].

Comment: Did you try passing your data as JSON?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data should be dumped:

```
a = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps([{"foo":"more_foo"}]))
```

or you can use the `json` key instead of `data`:

```
a = requests.post(url, json=[{"foo":"more_foo"}])
```

Comment: thank you for first editing my post and for providing me the missing part :)

Comment: yes, it did :) I upvoted as well,  let me know if u need something more.

Comment: Can you then accept the answer so users know it solves the issue!

Comment: Or you can pass a `json` payload using, perhaps unsurprisingly, `json=[{...}]`. You don't need to serialise it yourself.

Comment: Does it matter that the solution here changes the request from a PUT to a POST?